# How to connect server to VPN?

Tags: command-line, server, 16.04, vpn

I have a Virtual Private Server on DigitalOcean. I would like that my Ubuntu 16.04 server connects to a VPN before it connects to some other server (so that the DigitalOcean IP is not visible). Can I have some guidelines on how to do this?

**EDIT:**

I've tried with **vpnbook** but my server gets stuck. I followed this [How-To](http://www.vpnbook.com/howto/setup-openvpn-on-ubuntu) on www.vpnbook.com. Actually I don't think it's stuck but is maintaining the VPN connection. Here is a screen of my terminal:
[image: terminal screen]

At that moment it is "stuck". When I try to open a new session with putty I get an error that the connection timed out. When I close the VPN terminal and try to open a new session I also get a time out.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use openvpn, it's available through apt-get and is super easy to use via the command line on a server. You just need an .ovpn file to work with which can be downloaded from the VPN book website.

Comment: I presume you didn't take a look at the How-To link? :) 
Because you just described what I already did but I get stuck at step 4.